# Let $\Sigma$ be a Compact Riemann Surface of genus 1 then why $\mathbb{H}$ can't be a universal cover of $\Sigma$?

Tags: topological-groups, riemann-surfaces, isometry

My approach: If $\mathbb{H}$, the upper half plane in $\mathbb{C}$ were the universal cover of $\Sigma$, then $\pi_1{\Sigma} \subset PSL(2,R)$, is a discrete subgroup which is not possible, as $\mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be contained in PSL(2,R) as a discrete subgroup. But I don't know how to prove the later?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you embed $\pi_1 \Sigma$ in $Aut(\mathbb{H}) = PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You would have two matrices $A$, $B\in\text{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$
of infinite order which compute **up to sign**. That means their
squares commute, so we may assume they commute. Then one can show
that $B$ must be a linear combination of $A$ and $I$. The condition
that $B$ has determinant $1$ will mean that $A$ and $B$ will lie
in a one-parameter subgroup, so discreteness will finish off the job.

Comment: "one can show" means assuming $A = \scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and showing $BA = AB \implies B =\scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ ?